# Finding all possibilities as the fourth vertex of a parallogram

Tags: geometry

Consider the points $A=(-1,2), B=(6,4)$, and $C=(1,-20)$ in the plane.
For how many different points $D$ in the plane are $A,B,C,D$ the vertices of a parallelogram?

A) none

B) one

C) two

D) three

E) four

> $\textbf{My attempt}$: One parallelogram can be seen by putting the fourth vertex down and right of vertex $B$, i.e., this is the point located at $B+\vec{AC}$, where $\vec{AC}=C-A$.
>
> Another parallelogram can be seen by putting the fourth vertex up and to the left of vertex $B$, i.e., this is the point located at $B-\vec{AC}$.
>
> So I guessed C), which is two but the answer is supposed to be D), which is three. How do you see the third parallelogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One: with $\,AD||BC\;$ , two with $\,AC||BD\,$ , third with $\,AD||CB\,$ . Please note  the order of *my* vertices is not random: looking at the points on the plane, $\,D\,$ can be either up right from $\,A\,$ **but also**  down left from $\,A\,$, whereas for the other possibility we have $\,D\,$ right down from $\,C\,$. Draw it.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. The last vertex should be placed at $B+\vec{BC}-\vec{AB}$. This vertex lies to the left of the line passing through $\vec{AC}$.

Answer (score 0):

If A B C D is your parallelogram then since diagonals bisect each other.you can find 4th vertex at 3 different points[image: see image below]